# Cancel jquery auto refresh timer

Tags: jquery

I am using the following script to refresh a div once every minute.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function() { $('#posting').load('posts.php').fadeIn("slow"); }, 60000);
```

It works great, just as it should. My question is, is there a way that I can cancel that refresh when a user clicks on a particular link on the site. I have a comments section and when they click on View More Comments, i'd like for the site to not auto refresh anymore since that will mess up what they are looking at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `clearInterval`?

```
clearInterval(auto_refresh);
```

Comment: ok, my question back to you then is once that link is clicked and the timer is stopped, is there a way to turn it back on?

Comment: To "turn it back on" I would just call setInterval again, same as you did originally.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the link on the site has access to your `auto_refresh` variable.

```
// a link to clik
$('a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     clearInterval(auto_refresh);
});
```